# I am able to send messages to firebase but unable to retrive message from that and no error is coming(in Angular)

Tags: angular, firebase

I am unable to retrieve the message from the firebase but I am unable to send messages and no error is coming. I have searched and tried everything but unable to find the problem in my code.

MY APP COMPONENT

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {  AngularFireList, AngularFireDatabase } from 
'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  items: AngularFireList<any>;
  name: any;
  msgVal = '';

  constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase, public afAuth: 
  AngularFireAuth) {
  this.items = this.af.list('/messages' , ref => 
  ref.limitToLast(5));
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.name = this.afAuth.authState;
    console.log(this.name);
  }
  login() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  }
  logout() {
    return this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }
  Send(desc: string) {
    this.items.push({ message: desc, name: this.name.toString()});
    this.msgVal = '';
  }
}
```

MY HTML COMPONENT

```
<div class="row columns">
  <button (click)="login()" *ngIf="!name">Login With 
 Facebook</button>
  <button (click)="logout()" *ngIf="name">Logout</button>

  <input type="text" id="message" *ngIf="name" placeholder="Chat 
  here..." (keyup.enter)="Send($event.target.value)" 
   [(ngModel)]="msgVal" />

  <div class="chat-container" *ngFor="let item of (items |async)">
     <a href="#">{{item.name}}</a>

    <p>{{item.message}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

MY APP MODULE

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyA1VrfxnvWrde7-KIHovQAyeNDCTVyxFJ8',
  authDomain: 'appchat-2a8ec.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://appchat-2a8ec.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'appchat-2a8ec',
  storageBucket: 'appchat-2a8ec.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: '269198800174',
  appId: '1:269198800174:web:18bc3da705673518'
};


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I want to retrieve messages from firebase so that I could display them on the html page. No error is coming I don't know why this is happening. Please, help me to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

this.items = this.af.list('/messages' , ref => ref.limitToLast(5)).valueChanges();

When you use the pipe Async, it subscribes to your observable. In this case an Observable of (A List Or an Object that Value changes in your firebase database).